# Accidently flagged a post

Tags: bug, accepted-answer

I was using math exchange from my mobile and accidently flagged the last answer in this question [Can every Riemannian manifold be embedded in a sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790879/can-every-riemannian-manifold-be-embedded-in-a-sphere)

I accidently did this while scrolling down on my mobile and would like to undo this or someone undo it for me.

Thank you

Comment: There is no flag. But anyway, your flag would just be declined if it were nonsensical (and existent : P).

Comment: Accidental voting is more likely than accidental flagging.  Even on mobile access, the flagging requires a modal dialog to be completed.  If one did not intend to flag, the dialog can be dismissed without effect.